# Windows Phone 8.1 MediaElement Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I've been having very strange issue that I can't wrap my head around.

I created very simple WP 8.1 App to show the problem:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App6.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App6"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement1" Source="/Assets/Audio/clap_01.mp3"
                      Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="False" />

        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement2" Source="/Assets/Audio/click_01.mp3"
                      Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="False" />

        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement3" Source="/Assets/Audio/cowbell_01.mp3"
                      Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="False" />

        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement4" Source="/Assets/Audio/kick_01.mp3"
                      Visibility="Collapsed" AutoPlay="False" />

        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="147"
                Width="150" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />


    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace App6
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement1.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I click the button (especially just after turning on application) I get "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))" in the MediaElement1.Play(); line. The really strange fact is that the exception appear only if there are 4 or more MediaElements and if there are 1,2,3 of them it works perfectly. 
I tried to find some workaround this issue for all day and I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Why use so many MediaElements? Why not use one and just change the source?

Comment: It is just a simple example that shows my problem. In the app that I am actually making there are multiple buttons and each of the has different sound. I want them to be able to play sounds simultaneously. If there is any better way to do this (without using multiple MediaElements), I would be thankful for suggestions.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance of WP8.1, but can you try using `MediaPlayer`? For audio, you've got no need for an element in the visual tree, and `MediaPlayer` requires instantiation in code. If it doesn't exist in WP8.1, my apologies.

Comment: Try removing the visibility attribute of your media elements.

Comment: @ScottNimrod - Doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

As you want to play multiple sounds simultaneously , `MediaElement` is not going to work for you unfortunately.  You need to use XNA `SoundEffect` Class probably.

Comment: This class is no longer supported in WP 8.1